# I want my non administrator account to be able and only be able to access certain folders in windows 10

Tags: windows-10

First I want to make sure that every folder is unshared. Only my administrator account should be able to get that.

Then I want to create folders

```
H:\users\bob

H:\users\jane
```

I want user bob to be able to access h:\users\bob and that's it.

How do I set that up?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for User Access control on folders/files.

You can go through [this link](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb456977.aspx) on Microsoft TechNet.

**Edit 1:** Adding Instructions from above reference link

1.Open Windows Explorer. (Click Start, point to All Programs, point to Accessories, and then click Windows Explorer.)

2.Locate the file or folder for which you want to set permissions

3.Right–click the file or folder, click Properties, and then click the Security tab. (If you do not see the Security tab, you may not be joined to a domain. See To display the Security tab below.)

4.Do one of the following:

```
4.1 To set permissions for a group or user that does not appear in the Group or user names box, click Add. Type the name of the group or user you want to set permissions for and then click OK. (When adding a new user or group, by default, this user or group will have Read & Execute, List Folder Contents, and Read permissions.)

4.2 To change or remove permissions from an existing group or user, click the name of the group or user.
```

5.Do one of the following:

```
5.1 To allow or deny a permission, in the Permissions for User or Group box, select the Allow or Deny check box.

5.2 To remove the group or user from the Group or user names box, click Remove.
```

6.If the check boxes under Permissions for user or group are shaded or if the Remove button is unavailable, then the file or folder has inherited permissions from the parent folder.

Pasted below is snip from reference link

[image: The snip of permissions management GUI]

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.